# Why is this ListView not scrolling?

Tags: android, scroll, android-listview

I use 25% of the screen in one `ListView` and in other part, I use `EditText`, another `ListView`, `RadioButton`s, `Button`s. When I try to scroll `ListView` it doesn't scroll.

In total I use 6 `ListView`s on a single screen and all `ListView`s work except the main one which fills 25% of the screen.

I have already set all the other views focus to `false` and this main list focus to `true`.

Comment: Code, screenshots, more please. Which listview...?

Comment: ideally you shouldn't have more than one listview on a single screen..show us some code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution .. Its just the matter of height of ListView..

Comment: Its a matter of height, can you be more elaborative. What matter of height did you solve dude ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the ListView under a linearLayout and then try.